# can someone tell me why I'm getting this error?

Tags: python

```
class Solution:
  def remove(self,arr,target):
      if target in arr:
        arr.remove(target)
        remove(arr,target)
        return len(arr),arr
      else:
        return "not in the array"
ans=Solution()
print(ans.remove([3,2,2,3],3))
```

This is the Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ashut\Practice\scrap.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(ans.remove([3,2,2,3],3))
  File "c:\Users\ashut\Practice\scrap.py", line 5, in remove   
    remove(arr,target)
NameError: name 'remove' is not defined
```

Somehow the above program runs in google colab and I've tried restarting the runtime

Comment: Why are you trying to call `remove` recursively?

Comment: It's what the error message says. There is no function named `remove`. There is a `remove` method in the class `Solution` but you are not calling that.

Comment: In addition to what @Selcuk said, if you do want to call the `remove` method, you need to use `self.remove(arr, target)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the "self" tag before calling the function inside ur function.

```
     class Solution:
         def remove(self,arr,target):
         if target in arr:
             arr.remove(target)
             self.remove(arr,target)
             return len(arr),arr
         else:
             return "not in the array"
    ans=Solution()
    print(ans.remove([3,2,2,3],3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The temp variable name is arr, is that mean Array?
If so, the code "remove(arr, target)" is no need, **remove** this line, is OK.